# should I move my swap partition from time to time?

Tags: hard-drive, hardware, swap

I dont recall seeing this recommentation, but intuitively it makes sense... I'd guess swap space is used more aggressively than the rest of the hard drive, and therefore keeping it "too long in one place" would lead to damage.

Is this a good idea?

Does anyone know the effects of swap on the drive? Did anyone do a study or whitepaper? Can any argument from first principles, knowledge of the  or usage patterns be substanciated?

---

Re: similar questions

One proposed similar question informs us that swap partitions are no longer needed, and that Ubuntu will by default use a swap file if no swap partition is in use. The question remains, even if I have a swap file: should I try to move it around?

The other proposed similar question asks about performance. I am not asking how to make the computer faster, but rather how to make the hard drive last longer.

Also mentioned is the possibility that this is largely irrelevant, either because the hard drive resists a lot more than I expected, or because the usage pattern of swap is low enough.

(also, and as an aside: I am asking this mostly out of curiosity and nerding out. If people know of a 1% improvement, that is interesting. If they know that there can be no improvement, that is interesting too)

Comment: You might want to take a look at this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/349987/do-i-have-to-move-swap-partition-to-the-right-side

Comment: Does this answer your question? [One last thing before I install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158702/one-last-thing-before-i-install)

Comment: My swap space is almost never used, so perhaps my usage is different from yours.

Comment: I think the first question should actually be, "How much do you *actually* use your swap space?" Frankly, today's SSDs have a great MTBF, as do spinning platter disks. Chances are there will be no significant difference.